# Composite numbers that are close to being prime

Tags: primes

I'm working on a server that takes in a number and determines if it's prime or not.  I won't get into the details, but you can look at the source [here](https://github.com/wijagels/PrimeServer).

I'm writing unit tests to check if everything is working properly, and I want to check that it's not giving any false positives.  It only checks up to the square root of the number in question, so it can validate huge numbers without having reached them in the main list of prime numbers.  To make sure this isn't producing false positives, I'm looking for large numbers (10+ digits) that have factors that are very large, ideally close to the square root.

Is there a listing or a name for the numbers I've described?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for [Pseudoprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoprime)? Or perhaps [Semiprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiprime)?

Answer (score 0):

A simple test is to find the sum of the primes less than two million. The correct sum is 142913828922, so if you get a different total something has gone wrong. Another simple test is to calculate the millionth prime number, which is 15485863. Be aware that if you are using trial division to determine primality, both of these tests will take a while.

There are many web sites that give lists of prime numbers, which you could download and compare. I like [Tomas Oliveira e Silva's site](http://sweet.ua.pt/tos/primes.html); here's [another good one](https://primes.utm.edu/lists/).

If you are interested in prime numbers, I modestly recommend the essay [*Programming with Prime Numbers*](http://programmingpraxis.com/essays) at my blog, where you will also find lots of other prime number stuff.

By the way, the word that you are looking for is semi-prime, which is a composite number that is the product of two prime factors. It is not necessary that the two factors are near each other. If you want the additional restriction that the two factors are near each other, you might want to talk about RSA semi-primes, which are the keys to the RSA encryption algorithm, but they are typically much larger than ten digits.